# How to get heroku server timezone using command in Ubuntu

Tags: node.js

I am using heroku server. I want to know the heroku server timezone. I there any command available for that in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in command line:

```
date +%Z
```

Or in node.js you can get the timezone offset:

```
console.log((new Date()).getTimezoneOffset());
```